# Swagger incorrect API path

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using swagger and swagger UI to document my APIs. This is in a spring boot microservice set up. I am consolidating all swagger docs into my zuul gateway. This all works fine for displaying the documentation.
However when you try and execute the APIs using the Try It Out button, this fails as the path being used to hit the endpoint is incorrect. Specifically swagger seems to expect the downstream service to have no context root. Is there anyway i can configure this to accept a context root?

I've reproduced the issue on this repo https://github.com/craigmgordon/swagger 
If i run the services and hit the gateway on http://localhost:20000/swagger-ui.html i can see the docs for my two services are displayed correctly.

You can see the url is correct at the top of the page http://localhost:20000/prod/product/v2/api-docs

where 'prod' is the zuul route to the product-service
and 'product' is the product-service context route

If I try and use Try ITOut on the /products endpoint though, on execution i get a 404 as its tried to hit the url http://localhost:20000/prod/products
i.e. has ommitted the context route.
Correct url should be http://localhost:20000/prod/product/products

Has anyone had the same issue and found a resolution??

Answer (score 0):

#### Straightforward Fix

Don't use context (nor (mvc) servlet) path:

1. In employee-service and product-service `application.yaml`
2. In gateway-service (document controller, location... (of openapi definitions))

(Why should one need them "in cloud"? And if so, one should know what one does...and consequently)

Github-branch: https://github.com/xerx593/swagger-zuul/tree/fix-straight

(Swagger-Try-Out points to `http://localhost:20000/prod/products`, but it works!;)

---

#### Hacky Fix

Keeping/insisting on (non default) context (and/or servlet) path, we need to little trick like here (thx):

[Add context path to requests in swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61667717/592355)

(for most trivial cases) We can manipulate "operation path" like so:

```java
new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
  .pathProvider(
    new PathProvider() {
      @Override
      public String getApplicationBasePath() {
        return "/unknownFunction1/"; // ??
      }

      @Override
      public String getOperationPath(String s) {
        return s.replace("/employees", contextAndServletPath() + "employees");
      }

      @Override
      public String getResourceListingPath(String s, String s1) {
        return "/unknownFunction2/"; // ??
      }
    }
  ) // ...
```

where `contextAndServletPath()` could look like this:

```java
@Autowired
ServerProperties serverProps;
@Autowired
WebMvcProperties webMvcProps;

private String contextAndServletPath() {
  return serverProps.getServlet().getContextPath() + webMvcProps.getServlet().getPath();
}
```

... i don't like it.

Github-branch: https://github.com/xerx593/swagger-zuul/tree/fix-hack

(Swagger-try-out points to `http://localhost:20000/prod/product/products` ...)

(other+better "hacks" shown here: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2817)

---

#### Upgrade Fix

(sorry for late answer:)

Opening these old projects, my IDE "jumps at me" (with several warnings, security hotspots etc.) ...

This is how I ref*c?tored it to:

- java:17
- spring-boot:3
- springdoc:v2 (-> openapi:3)
- and (completely) different "gateway-tech"
- with many thanks to: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/blob/2.x/demo-microservices
- (persisting original functionality and fixing the "issue")
- (of course) without "context/servlet path"
- with cors mapping (due to alternative service registration/adressing)

https://github.com/xerx593/swagger-zuul/tree/fix-upgrade

(Swagger-tryout points to `http://<my/some_local_ip>:8081` and `http://<my/some_local_ip>:8082` respectively ...and works (also) due to "cors mapping")