# Add context path to requests in swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, netflix-eureka, contextpath

I have an eureka service which has a swagger. The eureka is on http://localhost:8050
and the service goes by name /service. The issue is that when i open swagger and try to make a request, it sends it to `http://localhost:8050/service/somecontroller`. The service has a context path "path" so it should be `http://localhost:8050/service/path/somecontroller`. This is the configuration of the swagger:

```
@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.test")).paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to change the context path of the swagger like this:

```java
@Value("${contextPath}")
private String contextPath;

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        //.host(retrieveHostHostname())
        .pathProvider(new PathProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getApplicationBasePath() {
            return contextPath;
        }

        @Override
        public String getOperationPath(String s) {
            return s.replace("somecontroller", contextPath+"/somecontroller");
        }

        @Override
        public String getResourceListingPath(String s, String s1) {
            return "/";
        }
    }).select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.test")).paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Springfox has an open issue ([#2817](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2817)) for your case, you can try one of the workarounds proposed by some users there.

Comment: unfortunately none of the suggested ways work for me